# Error: Biostrings not available for R 3.5.3

Tags: r

I tried many times to download a data set from Github by using

```
> devtools::install_github("crarlus/paprbag")
```

I did this while running R 3.4.4. The error consisted in the fact that > Biostrings was not available for this R version. Then following another post in stack overflow I installed the new version R 3.5.3. But I still get the same error message:

```
> devtools::install_github("crarlus/paprbag")
Downloading GitHub repo crarlus/paprbag@master
Skipping 1 packages not available: Biostrings
Installing 12 packages: ade4, Biostrings, data.table, doParallel, foreach, iterators, ranger, RcppEigen, segmented, seqinr, stringi, stringr
Installing packages into ‘/home/ibraim/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Error: (converted from warning) package ‘Biostrings’ is not available (for R version 3.5.3)
```

Do you have any idea how to fix this problem ? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The `Biostrings` package is not on CRAN but on [Bioconductor](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/3.8/bioc/html/Biostrings.html). To install it you should use:

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("Biostrings")
```

Comment: I thought Bioconductor was trying to push the `BiocManager::install("Biostrings)` method for installing packages now.